# Asp.net Hosted Blazor - Can i use app.config or web.config?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Im looking to add a web.config (or app.config) so that i can have different settings (e.g. DEV build vs RELEASE build, for instance).

Can i simply add a .config file and expect to read from it?
I noticed that there is also an option to add a appsettings.json (App Settings File).

Which one of these should i be using for Blazor Client app (hosted via Asp.net)?

Thanks

> **Updates**
>
> Based on the following [thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1152), i might just go with a settings
> file on the Server side and feeding it to the Client via API.
>
> Here is [another reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417616/trying-to-understand-the-new-behavior-of-appsettings-json-vs-web-config-in-net) for appsettings.json vs web.config
>
> I was able to find a more concrete example int this [article](https://medium.com/@st.mas29/microsoft-blazor-web-api-with-jwt-authentication-part-1-f33a44abab9d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use appsettings.Development.json and appsettings.json

Hope this helps...